# Is there an equivalent to xkill for Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7

In Linux there is a utility called `xkill` that changes the mouse pointer so that whatever you window you click is killed.  This saves you the trouble of finding its PID and killing it with `kill -9`.

Is there any similar utility for Windows 7 that can save me the trouble of going through the task manager?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653) can do this just fine. You use the icon in the toolbar on the top which looks like a target icon (It's next to the binoculars). As soon as you press it, your cursor turns into that target icon, and the process explorer window is hidden. Drag it over the window you want nuked, and release the mouse button. The process who created that window will be hilighted inside the Process Explorer UI. You can nuke the process at that point as normal (i.e. by pressing the <kbd>del</kbd> key)

**EDIT**: Oh, and this should work for any version of Windows NT as new or newer than Windows XP, not just Windows 7.

Comment: thanks! I had an ancient version of process explorer :-)

Comment: In my case it selected its own window. Killing the window made sysinternals kill itself. Seems to do a decent job though on non-frozen windows....

Answer (score 6):

There is [WiXkill](http://windows.xkill.free.fr/index_en.html). Another alternative is [Windows xKill](http://solo-dev.deviantart.com/art/Windows-xKill-100737525). [Here](http://www.deviantart.com/download/100737525/Windows_xKill_by_Solo_Dev.zip) is the direct download link.

Answer (score 0):

Found a port of xkill ([win-xkill](https://bitbucket.org/sta-ger/win-xkill/downloads/)) at bitbucket. Look at the [Readme.txt](https://bitbucket.org/sta-ger/win-xkill/src/master/Readme.txt) how to use it. You can (instead of using AutoHotkey) create a shortcut to the exe and enter a [keyboard shortcut](https://www.cnet.com/how-to/open-programs-with-keyboard-shortcuts-in-windows-10/) in the shortcuts properties dialog.

I tried it with Windows 10.