# kill a window with the mouse

Tags: windows-7, windows

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there an equivalent to xkill for Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/questions/230895/is-there-an-equivalent-to-xkill-for-windows-7)

hi all i want to know if someone has used an application that permits killi an application window using the mouse. In linux there are various utilities that provide this functionality. In windows i'm unable to find one.

I know that i can use taskill, but the problem is that i don't know the process name and either the title name because the window doesn't have a title. Some known program create this window that doesn't have any way to close it.

Comment: Erm... can't you use the mouse to click that little `[x]` button in the upper right of the windows?

Comment: @nhinkle lol, obviously the created window doesn't have any type of control mechanism, that inclue the 3 standard buttons. In my particular case was the application "7 taskbar tweaker" that create a permanent "taskbar inspector" window that behave as i say. Following the link that was suggested by the moderators i found this app http://solo-dev.deviantart.com/art/Windows-xKill-100737525 that provide the functionality that i need, :D